# Is it possible to use Auto Layout in a UITextField's leftView?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextfield, icons

I want to customize a `UITextField`'s `leftView` with a view that is automatically sized depending on its contents:

```
func set(leftImage image: UIImage) {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    let paddingContainer = UIView()
    // This is the crucial point:
    paddingContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    paddingContainer.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.pin(toMarginsOf: paddingContainer)
    leftView = paddingContainer
    leftViewMode = .always
}
```

where the `pin` method just pins the image view on all four sides to the margins of the `paddingContainer`:

```
func pin(toMarginsOf view: UIView) {
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
        .bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor),
        leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor),
        trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor)
    ])
}
```

On iOS 12, everything works as expected, but on iOS versions < 12, the image is completely misplaced. It's not even within the bounds of the text field but in the upper left corner of my view controller's view.

To me it seems like older versions of iOS don't support using Auto Layout inside the view that you set as a text field's `leftView`. The documentation states:

> The left overlay view is placed in the rectangle returned by the `leftViewRect(forBounds:)` method of the receiver.

but it doesn't state *how* it's placed there: By using constraints or by setting the frame directly.

**Are there any reliable sources or educated guesses if using Auto Layout is supported at all for the `leftView`?**

Answer (score 2):

```
extension UITextField{
func setLeft(image: UIImage, withPadding padding: CGFloat = 0) {
        let wrapperView = UIView.init(
            frame: CGRect.init(
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                width: bounds.height,
                height: bounds.height
            )
        )
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        wrapperView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: wrapperView.leadingAnchor,
                constant: padding
            ),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: wrapperView.trailingAnchor,
                constant: -padding
            ),
            imageView.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: wrapperView.topAnchor,
                constant: padding
            ),
            imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: wrapperView.bottomAnchor,
                constant: -padding
            )
            ])
        leftView = wrapperView
        leftViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can set its frame on layout subviews function like this

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let lv = self.leftView {
        lv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.height, height: self.bounds.height)
    }
   }
```